# Selenium webdriver pageobjects login failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am writing a new Web app test using selenium web driver. I have gone through various example however each page returns next page class. The only doubt I have in my mind is if the login fails due to password change etc? in such scenario page is returned back to login page with error message. If anyone has experience with this can you please let me know how have you handled such scenario.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do 2 login request. First to get login page with GET method & second with user name , password and other necessary fields with POST method.

Comment: Thanks Quality-Expert. I am pretty new to this. Do you have an example or link which i can refer to please.

Comment: @Avi - Sure, you can do login to any site using jmeter via 2 ways.. 1 - Using recording , 2 - Using manual http request and authentication passing.                                            Please check below , That will help you get exact thing which you want : http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if you still staying in your login page, and if you do - to attempt re-login again.
For example, you got LoginPageObject in return after unsuccessful login attempt.

For example, "trivial" solution:

```
while(loginPageObject != null){
 loginPageObject = loginPageObject.attemptToLogin();
}
```